# NetSuite - Saved search join with location inventory data

Tags: netsuite

I'm looking to find a way to join/add location inventory data to a search (this will then be used in a script)

I have a search as below that takes several work orders and sums the total usage requirement by item.   I would like to also include the current on-hand qty per item but for multiple locations (i.e. LocA and LocB).

```
i.e
Item   Remaining  Quantity   Built   onHandLocA   onHandLocB
A      10         20         10      99           0
B      20         20         0       23           659
C      30         30         0       2            33
```

I know I can get this data by iterating through each line and then get the value from the sublist, but wondered if there is a way to do this via the search join.

```
var workorderSearch = nlapiSearchRecord("workorder",null,
[
   ["type","anyof","WorkOrd"], 
   "AND", 
   ["status","anyof","WorkOrd:D","WorkOrd:A","WorkOrd:B"], 
   "AND", 
   ["itemsource","anyof","STOCK"], 
   "AND", 
   ["formulanumeric: INSTR('11518,11624', {number}) ","notequalto","0"]
], 
[
   new nlobjSearchColumn("item",null,"GROUP").setSort(false), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("formulanumeric",null,"SUM").setFormula("{quantity}-{built}"), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("quantity",null,"SUM"), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("built",null,"SUM")
]
);
```

Comment: Often done using a `case()` statement in a formula  in the search with one branch of the case checking the location and returning the qty and the other as an ELSE returning 0.

Answer (score 0):

`new nlobjSearchColumn("locationquantityavailable","item","SUM")`

or

`new nlobjSearchColumn("formulanumeric", null, "SUM").setFormula("DECODE({item.inventorylocation}, 'LocA',{locationquantityavailable},0)")`

The problem with grabbing item inventory location data is the rest of the data gets duplicated for each location, so if your work order requires a quantity of 10 and you have 2 locations, the summarized saved search will return quantity of 20 (10 quantity x 2 locations).
So, you will need to make all of your other aggregate columns into formulas as well.

`[
   new nlobjSearchColumn("item",null,"GROUP").setSort(false), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("formulanumeric", null, "SUM").setFormula("DECODE({item.inventorylocation},'LocA',{quantity}-{built},0)"), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("formulanumeric", null, "SUM").setFormula("DECODE({item.inventorylocation},'LocA',{quantity},0)",null,"SUM"), 
   new nlobjSearchColumn("formulanumeric", null, "SUM").setFormula("DECODE({item.inventorylocation},'LocA',{built},0)",null,"SUM")
]`